# How can I correct linear regression for a large (unknown) constant added to all of my input features?

Tags: r, machine-learning

Suppose I have an input feature vector containing 10 input features, each with order of magnitude around `1E-7`.

When I run linear regression with the `log` of these input features, I get an `R^2` value of around `0.98`.

However, if I add `1E-2` to each of my input features before running through the above fit, I get an `R^2` value of `0.5616`.

The problem is that I will not know a priori that the constant that was added to my input features was `1E-2`, so I cannot simply subtract off that quantity every time.

Is there a general way to correct for a large, unknown constant added to my input feature set?

Here is a sample input file:
http://stanford.edu/~hq6/13

Here is a corresponding output file:
http://stanford.edu/~hq6/15

Here is some code that is used for training:

```
input_features = read.csv('InputFeatures.csv', header=F)

# Adding constant error term to all input features
input_features = input_features + 1E-2
# How can we correct for this constant if we do not know what the constant is beforehand?

input_features[input_features <= 0] = 1E-10
input_features = log(input_features)
output = read.csv('Output.csv', header=F)

full_data = data.frame(input_features,  output)
summary(lm(V1.1 ~ ., data=full_data))
```

When this code is run without the line `input_features = input_features + 1E-2`, I get an `R-squared` of approximately `0.98` from  the `summary` output.

When this line is put in, then the `R-squared` of less than `0.5`.

Comment: you should attach your code and data in a simple, reproducible way

Answer (score 1):

So you're suggesting your dataset fits `y = A + B*exp(C*x)` .   Why not do a direct fit using `nls` or other nonlinear fitting tools?

If you wish to do a linear fit to the log of both sides,  it should be obvious from the rules of logarithms (e.g.  log(ab) = log(a) + log(b) ) that you cannot separate out the effect of two summed terms.

Comment: Are you implying that using a nonlinear fitting tool will enable me to separate the effect of two summed terms?

Comment: @merlin2011  well, yeah, seeing as it'll give you the fitted values of A, B, and C in my example.

Comment: can you provide the full command line you used in the `nls` function in your answer?

Comment: The formula argument for the nls command is a little tricky to use. Do you have to manually specify a coefficient for each column?

Comment: @merlin maybe the easiest way to go at it, since you are new to math and R, is  `nls(y~I(a+b*exp(c*x), start=list(a=, b=,c=))`where of course you have to enter initial values for the coefficients.

Comment: I'm not sure how to handle the multiple input features though. Do I have to create named parameters for each of my input features or is there some kind of vector notation I can use to work around it?

Comment: The output feature is named V1.1, and the input features are named V1, V2, ...V15 in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Linear regression on the R^10 results in 11 real numbers being coefficients of the 10-dimensional hyperplane. From your post it seems that you have **one** ("value of ...") or at most two ("R^2") which still seems wrong.

Or maybe by R^2 you meant residuals error?

Linear regression itself is invariant to adding a constant, as long as it does not lead to some numerical imprecision and you add it to **all** your features. If you add to just **one** then it is quite obvious that it will change results - as this dimension may become more/less important (depending on the sign of the constant). In order to make it invariant to such operations you can **normalize** your data (by linearly scaling to the interval or normalizing to mean=0 and std=1)

Comment: Please see my updated question. By R^2, I mean the `R-squared` in the output of the `summary` function.

Comment: It represents the proportion of the variance in the output explained by the input.